# Simple algebra rearrangment

Tags: linear-algebra

$f(x) = (x^2 + 1)^{0.5} - 1$.

Show algebraically that $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{(x^2 + 1)^{0.5} + 1}$.

Can someone help me solve this part of an exam question?

It may seem easy but I'm not sure how to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: $(\sqrt a - \sqrt b)(\sqrt a + \sqrt b) = a - b \,$.

Hint 2: Your $f(z)$ can be written as $(\sqrt a - \sqrt b) \,$.

Comment: So do I rationalise?

Comment: @James: May be that it is called like that, I don't know.

Comment: No I don't think I'm right. Have you got another hint?

Comment: @James: There are 2 hints now :)

Comment: Do you mean (x^2 + 1)^0.5 - (1)^0.5

Comment: @James: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

A little extra hint: If f(x)=first expression and f(x)= second expression then the first expression = second expression and combine that with the first answer.

Comment: I don't understand???

Comment: You put for simplicity $y=(x^2+1)^½ $ to get $y-1=x^2/(y+1) $
you then multiply both sides with y-1 get $ (y-1)(y+1)=x^2$ (I did not change the remaining right hand side, $x^2$, in terms of y).
You might know that $ (y-1)(y+1)=y^2-1$. In any case you use that equality. Then you go back and put $ (x^2+1)^½$ instead of y in this expression to get  (x^2+1)-1=x^2 which is true.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply $f(x)$ by $\frac{(x^2+1)^{0.5}+1}{(x^2+1)^{0.5}+1}$.